# Browser is rendering page based on old php source code despite uploading new ones (Cpanel)

Tags: laravel, cpanel

The project is based on laravel and  uploaded in cpanel. When I view the file from file manager it shows new source code, but browser is rendering pages based on old ones that I already deleted. Not the case with every page however, some are showing new updates.
I have tried uploading after clearing laravel cache and server apcu and opcache cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a caching problem, try deleting files in `storage\framework\views\` directory.

Comment: this fixed it. Thank you!